# How to establish operator precedence?

Tags: c++, stack, operator-precedence

I am trying to create an infix to postfix math statement conversion function. I am using a stack to store operators, and if the current index has greater precedence, it is supposed to be pushed onto the stack. We are using operators like {,[,(,+,-,*,/,%. I am getting strange behavior whenever I try to compare these values (stringIndex < operator_stack.top()). I suspect this is because it is comparing the ASCII values. Is there a way to override these values with my own (for example, change * to have greater precedence than +)?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  But it requires you to make your own programming language that is a lot like C++, but not C++.

Comment: No, there is no way to change the precedence of operators in C++.

Comment: What is it you really want to do? You see, there's actually a workaround available if you wanna "change" the operator precedence. Do not take in the operator as an operator, but scan it as a character and then implement your own string parsing. You are welcome to take a [look](https://github.com/kesarling/expression-evaluation/tree/master/expression_evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing some sort of ASCII comparison? That's probably a mistake. I would create an Operator class and program a precedence check. Then you would see a * and create a Multiply Operator, and that's what you push onto your stack.

Comment: We can also have it with a switch case, like we do for expression evaluation. But I think this is an xy-problem